# Smarty's outputfilter.trimwhitespace.php for Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, smarty, zend-view

There is output filter for Smarty where it removes all whitespaces and converts the whole html to one long string, before rendering it. Is there anything like that for ZF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Zend_Filter_Minify_Html`  component

http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Filter_Minify_Html+-+Nick+Daugherty

Zend_Filter_Minify_Html is a filter to reduce the size of Html strings and files by removing extra white spaces and new line spaces, resulting in faster client downloads

Comment: You should specify that this is not a native Filter and there isn't in the standard library.

Comment: Yes . That is why I given reference link

Comment: I understand your good will but for a person who is approaching ZF, this could not be so clear.

Comment: I think this is close to what I was looking for. But can this be integrated with Zend MVC and do the minifying automatically before sending the view script to the browser?